# How to create a cube in 2D view and scale it based on a point/anchor? Then visualize the cube in 3D

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a cube/wall in `2D` view and change its scale from one side based on a pivot or anchor, after that see the cube in `3D` view.

Here is a [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53bWbujdBl8) of what I want to achieve:

Basically taking a room shape and manipulate its scale than view in `3D`. The live demo is available [here](https://visualizer.somanyceramics.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at this link to the unity forum for vector editing. It is a good starting point on the idea. You would just need to get the starting positions for the shape.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14567/editing-mesh-vertices-in-unity.html

Comment: I tried Mesh Deformation. I am now able to achieve the effect upto a certain extent.

The FULL TUTORIAL YOU CAN FIND HERE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-pqEHR1jnw Tutorial by matt...

Comment: However, there is another issue I am facing now. When I deform the mesh(cube in my case). the deformation is very extreme. I want to limit the deformation to clamp between two values.

Here is a youtube link describing the issue(see around 0:15 seconds from start)

https://youtu.be/hztNOUDXlkE

Comment: use `Mathf.Clamp`